# image zoom effect on hover

Tags: html, css

The idea is to create a zoom effect on mouseover. But since the height is 'auto' the zoomed in image doesn't contain in the div and increases in height. I have to keep the height 'auto' for responsive design purpose. A way out would be appreciated. Following is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/nitish_8/zaeZ4/

```
<div class="item">
<img src="images/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="images/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="images/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="images/2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try out following code for item div hover, hope this will help you

```
.item:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all 21s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: al 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transform:  scale(1.1) ;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) ;
    -moz-transform:  scale(1.1) ;
    -o-transform:  scale(1.1)  ;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1)  ; 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but it isn't helping. just in case i wasnt clear in my question i wanna say again- I want the height of the div to remain constant, and the img zoom within that div. The 'auto' value to the div height helps the height of the div to increase along with the image height. I do not want that.

Comment: I think its not working in jsfiddle but working fine in chrome and IE. I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the `ovewflow` attribute from the `item` class to make the `div` not to clip the enlarged image

Comment: The whole idea of my query is that i can clip the image when it increases in height. I want the height of the div to remain constant, and the img zoom within that div. Now the div height increases with the image since its on 'auto'.

Answer (score 0):

code from TalkersCode.com here is a complete tutorial http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/image-zoom-in-on-hover-using-css3.php

```
.item img 
{
 max-width: 100%;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 width:250px;
 height:220px;
}
.item:hover img 
{
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
```